# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defaultPrevented')

Tags: javascript, html, django, error-handling, bootstrap-5

I seem to be getting a script error that mentions both bootstrap alert and my own close alert tag.
I have a script that closes alerts after 2.5s when a script is created. It is tied to user actions, for example if a user creates a blog post or deletes a comment, an alert shows with the User task and then auto closes the tag. I seem to be getting a Uncaught TypeError in console and can't figure out why. I can only speculate that it's because it's looking for a alerts msg that isn't there yet?

script.js

```js
// // Event listener for auto close message function using DOM Content Loaded
// // Javascript function for auto close messages

// document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", alertTimeout);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (alertTimeoutalertTimeout) => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    let messages = document.getElementById("msg");
    let alert = new bootstrap.Alert(messages);

    alert.close();
  }, 2500);
});
```

index.html bootstrap script

```
<!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

[Console Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFL6N.png)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defaultPrevented')
    at Q.close (alert.js:38:60)
    at script.js:11:11
close @ alert.js:38
(anonymous) @ script.js:11
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ script.js:7
```

Alert.js
Seems to be the EVENT_CLOSE that is showing as error

```js
// Public
  close() {
    const closeEvent = EventHandler.trigger(this._element, EVENT_CLOSE)

    if (closeEvent.defaultPrevented) {
      return
    }

    this._element.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME_SHOW)

    const isAnimated = this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_FADE)
    this._queueCallback(() => this._destroyElement(), this._element, isAnimated)
  }
```

I have tried to add a document ready to the script and have tried different ways to write and load the script but seems to be the same outcome as always. I have also tried using a older version of bootstrap js link and that works so no console error but then my modal and navbar collapse stopped working so I have to have correct version of the script.

Comment: updated with alert.js sorry about that

Comment: You clearly not be having anything inside the `closeEvent`. Can you put a breakpoint inside this function and see what is happening?

Comment: the alert.js is from the bootstrap js library so I cant add anything to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code..

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (alertTimeoutalertTimeout) => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#msg").alert("close");
  }, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and no console errors thank you very much